# Javascript for loop seems to exit or get stuck after the first iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a contact us form that i want to check with javascript before submitting it to php. so when i call the function verify(), by placing alert("hello")'s throughout the code, i determined that it was exiting after the first iteration of the second loop. does anyone know why?

Heres my html form code:

```
<div id="errortext">
</div>
<form id="contact" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <h1>Fields marked with a * are required</h1>
    <p>Full Name*</p>
    <input type="text" class="single" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="name" /><br />
    <p>E-Mail Address*</p>
    <input type="text" class="single" placeholder="E-Mail Address" name="email" id="email" /><br />
    <p>Phone Number</p>
    <input type="text" class="single" placeholder="Phone Number" name="number" id="number" /><br />
    <p>Subject</p>
    <input type="text" class="single" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" id="subject" /><br />
    <p>Message*</p>
    <textarea placeholder="Message" name"message" id="message"></textarea><br />
    <input type="button" id="submitb" onclick="verify()" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

and heres my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verify()
    {
        var rgood = true, nrgood = true;
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var phone = document.getElementById("number");
        var subject = document.getElementById("subject");
        var message = document.getElementById("message");
        var error = document.getElementById("errortext");

        var relements = new Array(name, email,  message);
        var nrelements = new Array(phone, subject);

        var relementsng = new Array;
        var nrelementsng = new Array;
        var relementsngp = new Array;
        var nrelementsng = new Array;

        for (var x = 0; x < relements.length; x++)
        {
            if (relements[x].value == "")
            {
                rgood = false;
                relementsng.push(relements[x]);
                relementsngp.push(relements[x].placeholder);
            }
        }

        for (var y = 0; y < nrelements.length; y++)
        {
            if (nrelements[y].value == "")
            {
                nrgood = false;
                nrelementsng.push(nrelements[y]);
                nrelementsngp.push(nrelements[y].placeholder);
            }
        }
        alert("hello");
        if (!rgood)
        {
            error.textContent = "All required fields are not filled out! These fields must be filled out: " + nrelementsngp.toString() + "!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of using `alert`s, set breakpoints, step through to the code and inspect variables. That should quickly tell you what the problem is. It's a good opportunity to improve your debugging skills. Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: I created a small isolated test to prove that your loops work: http://jsfiddle.net/7LPj3/ most likely there is something wrong in your code where rnelements or relements are null or undefined so they aren't getting added to the array. Use Web Inspector or Firebug, set a breakpoint at your for loop and check the value of your arrays.

Comment: Also I recommend getting into the practice of naming your variables something that isn't nonsensical as soon as possible :-) they all look so similar it's hard to tell if you don't have a simple mispelling error somewhere

Comment: @netpoetica His variables actually make sense. `nrelements` stand for "non required elements" `nrelementsg` stand for "non required elements that are good" and `nrelementsng` stand for "non required elements that are not good", so yeah, if the OP can understand the code it's fine. He should probably comment the code for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is all right except this typo :

```
line23: nrelementsngp.push(nrelements[x].placeholder);
                    ^
line31: nrelementsngp.push(nrelements[y].placeholder);
                    ^
```

---

On my browser, the error message below was shown.

```
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: nrelementsngp"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! the typo wasnt on those lines that you specified but on my variable declaration. i declared nrelementsng twice rather than having a nrelementsngp. the code works perfectly now thanks everyone (i would give you a vote up but i dont have enough "reputation" yet haha)

Comment: Don't forget to vote to close the question. There is a close reason for typos.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var relementsng = new Array;
    var nrelementsng = new Array;
    var relementsngp = new Array;
    var nrelementsng = new Array; // <<---- Change this line to
```

To

```
    var nrelementsngp = new Array;
```

Because

```
for (var y = 0; y < nrelements.length; y++){
    if (nrelements[y].value == ""){
        nrgood = false;
        nrelementsng.push(nrelements[y]);
        nrelementsngp.push(nrelements[y].placeholder); // This place is causing your script to crash
    }
}
```

The identifier `nrelementsngp` isn't declared.

Comment: yup i figured that out right after @naota mentioned a typo. thanks though!